# Deep copy structure C++

Tags: c++, object, deep-copy

I am trying to build a deep copy function for my structure. In the main program I try to deep copy a into c so finally it should print the string "B". What am I doing wrong? I know that there is some obscure pointer stuff that I am missing right now.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Thing {

        size_t length;
        std::string txt;
        struct Thing *things[];
};

struct Thing *deepCopy(struct Thing *origin) {

        Thing tmp;
        tmp.length = origin->length;
        for(int i=0;i<tmp.length; ++i)
            tmp.things[i] = deepCopy(origin->things[i]);

        return &tmp;
}

int main() {

        Thing a, b, *c;

        a.length = 1;
        a.things[0] = &b;
        a.txt = "A";
        b.txt = "B";
        b.length = 0;
        c = deepCopy(&a);

        cout<<c->txt;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Enable all warnings, and the issue will be obvious (it's `-Wall` in gcc). It'll help you in the future.

Comment: what an ungodly mixture of C++ and C!

Comment: Apart from local argument address mentioned already, you also have an undefined behavior here `struct Thing *things[];`

Answer (score 7):

The best way to perform a deep copy is to write code so that the compiler does it for you. The compiler automatically generates a copy constructor and assignment operator that copies every member of the object. So long as every member knows how to copy itself, this will usually work the way you want. It probably won't work automatically if you have pointers and manually managed memory, as pointers don't know if they own what they point to. If you don't use any pointers, you are usually fine.

So if you write your object like this:

```
struct Thing
{
    std::string txt;
    std::vector<Thing> things;
};
```

Copying it will just work automatically.

```
Thing a;
Thing b = a; // just works
```

I removed the size field because `std::vector` knows its own size, so it is not needed.

Comment: Finally a proper answer :)

Comment: The fact is that I need that struct as is :) I need to implement the deep copy function..

Comment: @user5504743 Whoever gave you that struct is not good at programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return address of local variable. At the moment function is finished it's not valid anymore. Pass two pointers (source and destination) to function instead

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a pointer to an object with automatic storage duration, since the object is in an indeterminant state after control leaves the function scope  dereferencing it with `c` is undefined behavior.  Either return a full copy of the object and then take its address and put it in `c`, or pass a reference or pointer to `c` into the function (or make `deepCopy` a member function of Thing and assign to the instance instead of a temporary, which is probably the best solution).